# Show TextField above keyboard

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

I know there are many opened questions on this, I've tried many, but none worked in my case.. So I want to have the TextField pop up above the keyboard, then go back to its original position, when keyboard is not showing.

Original position:

[image: Original position]

When the keyboard pops up, my screen overflows like so:

[image: Overflowed screen]

Code:

```dart
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Chat',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Chalet',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: widget.deviceWidth * 0.06),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: whitePrimary,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: widget.deviceHeight * 0.8,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _messages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListView(
                        children: [Text(_messages[index])],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              const Divider(height: 1.0),
              _buildTextComposer()
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget _buildTextComposer() {
        return SizedBox(
          width: widget.deviceWidth,
          child: TextField(
            controller: _textFieldController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
              disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: whitePrimary,
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.send_rounded,
                  color: orangePrimary,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: widget.deviceWidth * 0.03),
              hintText: 'Write a message...',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

where `deviceHeight`
and `deviceWidth`

```dart
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    
        double deviceWidth = size.width;
        double deviceHeight = size.height;
```

Comment: Don't use `widget.deviceHeight * 0.8` to set the height of the ListView. Wrap the ListView with Expanded instead.

Comment: Please post it as an answer, it did solve the issue with the textField also, @DhafinRayhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use device height from `MediaQuery` to set the `ListView` height, but instead, wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded`.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        // ...
      ),
    // ... other children
  ],
)
```

Comment: This answers is correct and that Dhafin Rayhan is really help to other. good work bro

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with `signleChildScrollView`. Wrap your root widget with `signleChildScrollView`. I'll update with full sources code.

Comment: Using Expanded widget instead of widget.deviceHeight * 0.8 as I was using already solved my issue